The Modal window from the list using react-beautiful-dnd is draggable. How can I fix it?
I recently made a react typescript project, and it needed a draggable list, so I made it using react-beautiful-dnd. Later, I set modal to float inside the component I set to draggable, but I don't want this modal to be draggable. Additionally, I need to set modal to come out from each PlanListItem.
Here's my code. PlanList is outer contents of PlanListItem, and EditPlanModal is my modal component which causes problem :
PlanListItem.tsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./PlanListItem.css";
import DefaultImage_Small from "../assets/images/DefaultImage_Small.svg";
import EditPlanModal from "./EditPlan/EditPlanModal";
import EditPlanHeader from "./EditPlan/EditPlanHeader";
import EditPlanList from "./EditPlan/EditPlanList";

interface PlanListItemProps {
  content: string;
}

const PlanListItem: React.FC<PlanListItemProps> = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="planlist_state-layer" onClick={openModal}>
      <img
        src={DefaultImage_Small}
        alt="Not Found"
        className="leading-element"
      />
      <div className="planlist_content">
        <p className="planlist_headline">Date Plan Title</p>
        <p className="planlist_category">2000.01.01 Location // 추후 개발</p>
        <p className="planlist_supporting-text">Dating Plan에 대한 한줄 소개</p>
      </div>

      <EditPlanModal isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={closeModal}>
        <EditPlanHeader />
        <EditPlanList />
      </EditPlanModal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlanListItem;

PlanListItem.css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400&display=swap");

p {
margin: 0;
}

.planlist_state-layer {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: flex-start;
gap: 16px;
width: 80vw;
height: 120px;
padding: 12px 16px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.leading-element {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
}

.planlist_content {
position: relative;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: flex-start;
gap: 8px;
width: 1688px;
height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.planlist_headline {
color: rgba(29, 27, 32, 1);
font-size: 22px;
line-height: 127%;
font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
}

.planlist_category {
color: rgba(73, 69, 79, 1);
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 143%;
font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}

.planlist_supporting-text {
color: rgba(73, 69, 79, 1);
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 143%;
font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}

PlanList.tsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  DragDropContext,
  Droppable,
  Draggable,
  DropResult,
} from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import PlanListItem from "./PlanListItem"; // Figma에서 변환한 Plan 컴포넌트
import AddPlan from "./AddPlan"; // Add Plan 버튼 컴포넌트
import "./PlanList.css"; // 추가적인 스타일 적용
import Favorite_Gray from "../assets/icons/Favorite_Gray.svg";
import Favorite_Red from "../assets/icons/Favorite_Red.svg";

interface PlanItem {
  id: string;
  content: string;
  liked: boolean;
}

const PlanList: React.FC = () => {
  const [plans, setPlans] = useState<PlanItem[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedPlans = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem("plans") || "[]"
    ) as PlanItem[];
    setPlans(storedPlans);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("plans", JSON.stringify(plans));
  }, [plans]);

  const handleAddPlan = () => {
    const newPlan: PlanItem = {
      id: `plan-${plans.length + 1}`,
      content: `New Date Plan ${plans.length + 1}`,
      liked: false,
    };
    setPlans([...plans, newPlan]);
  };

  const handleDeletePlan = (id: string) => {
    const newPlans = plans.filter((plan) => plan.id !== id);
    setPlans(newPlans);
  };

  const handleToggleLike = (id: string) => {
    const updatedPlans = plans.map((plan) =>
      plan.id === id ? { ...plan, liked: !plan.liked } : plan
    );
    setPlans(updatedPlans);
  };

  const handleDragEnd = (result: DropResult) => {
    if (!result.destination) return;

    const newPlans = Array.from(plans);
    const [movedPlan] = newPlans.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    newPlans.splice(result.destination.index, 0, movedPlan);

    setPlans(newPlans);
  };

  return (
    <div className="plan-list-container">
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
        <Droppable droppableId="planList">
          {(provided) => (
            <div
              className="plan-list"
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
            >
              {plans.map((plan, index) => (
                <Draggable key={plan.id} draggableId={plan.id} index={index}>
                  {(provided, snapshot) => (
                    <div
                      ref={provided.innerRef}
                      {...provided.draggableProps}
                      {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                      className={`plan-item ${
                        snapshot.isDragging ? "dragging" : ""
                      }`}
                    >
                      <PlanListItem content={plan.content} />
                      <img
                        src={plan.liked ? Favorite_Red : Favorite_Gray}
                        alt="Favorite"
                        className="favorite-icon"
                        onClick={() => handleToggleLike(plan.id)}
                      />
                    </div>
                  )}
                </Draggable>
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
      <div className="add-plan-container" onClick={handleAddPlan}>
        <AddPlan /> {/* Add Plan 버튼 */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlanList;

PlanList.css
.plan-list-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.plan-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 16px;
}

.plan-item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.dragging {
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.favorite-icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add-plan-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

EditPlanModal.tsx
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./EditPlanModal.css";

interface ModalProps {
children: React.ReactNode;
isOpen: boolean;
onClose: () =\> void;
}

const Modal: React.FC\<ModalProps\> = ({ children, isOpen, onClose }) =\> {
useEffect(() =\> {
const handleOutsideClick = (event: MouseEvent) =\> {
const modal = document.getElementById("editplan_modal-content");
if (modal && !modal.contains(event.target as Node)) {
onClose();
}
};

    if (isOpen) {
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleOutsideClick);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleOutsideClick);
    }
    
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleOutsideClick);
    };

}, \[isOpen, onClose\]);
if (!isOpen) return null;

return (
\<div className="editplan_modal-overlay"\>
\<div className="editplan_modal-content" id="editplan_modal-content"\>
{children}
\</div\>
\</div\>
);
};

export default Modal;

EditPlanModal.css
.editplan_modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.editplan_modal-content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

I'd changed my .tsx and .css files several times but it couldn't be solved.
